# Can only connect a SQL Server data source to Excel if running Excel as admin?

Tags: sql-server, excel, database-connection

I can only connect a SQL Server data source to Excel if I am running Excel as admin.

Just to clarify, to connect to SQL Server I go to:

Data - Get Data - From Database - From SQL Server Database. Enter server and database names. Use Windows credentials - use alternate credentials. I tried both a non-admin windows login and an admin Windows login, in domain/username format. Applied settings to database only.

If I do the above when Excel is NOT running as admin, then neither of the above logins works.

When I do the above with Excel running as admin, both logins work

Is there any way to do this without running Excel as admin? Not all our users are admins, so wont be able to run it like this

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried to use sql server credentials?

Comment: perhaps making these group of people admin on their local machines would do the trick.

Comment: @ZekiGumus We dont use SQL server credentials, it has to be Windows authentication

Comment: @junketsu I cant have all users as local admins, as regular domain users will use this data connection too, so would need it to work without setting all users up as local admin. Any other ideas?

Comment: then perhaps its time to create a service account and have the connection string embedded to using this [sa] account to access the server.

Comment: it doesnt matter what connection details i use, the issue is that Excel has to be run as Admin (right click Excel icon - run as Admin) before the connection can work. That is what I cant understand, and need to find a way around